# Replacing in-line div style

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I'm trying to replace the in-line styling of a div using Dojo. I only want to change the min-height property, without affecting any other in-line properties.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div id="divid" class="divclass" style="width: 950px; min-height: 225px;">
```

Here is my script string:

```
dojo.query('div.divclass').css( "min-height", "0px" );
```

But it seems to have no effect at all. If I try to swap the `.css()` for `.attr()` it works fine except it removes the other styling - `.attr('style', 'min-height:0px');`
Manually editing the div code is not an option so I'm looking for a workaround. I also tried appending another class but the in-line styling overwrites it.

I got the `.css()` part from a jQuery site so maybe it's not compatible with Dojo? Sorry I'm pretty new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative for Dojo as well (compared to jQuery), however, the function is called `style()` in stead of `css()`, for example:

```
dojo.query('div.divclass').style( "min-height", "0px" );
```

Also, this functionality is not available by default, you also need to load the module `dojo/NodeList-dom`, because it contains extra DOM functionalities for the `NodeList` (which is the list of nodes you get when you use the `dojo/query` module).

Another small thing to notice: be sure that the DOM is loaded before you're going to query it, if the DOM isn't loaded yet, there's nothing to query either.

A full example (using AMD) would be:

```
require([ "dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(query) {
    query('div.divclass').style( "min-height", "0px" );
});
```

The `dojo/domReady!` module is similar to `$(document).ready()` in jQuery, it makes sure that the DOM is loaded before you query it.

The working example can also be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eu9Br/

Comment: Thank you! I got it working using your method, I had to replace "min-height" with "minHeight" in your code as the hyphen was causing issues.